# How many number of attachments per e-mail by MS Outlook 2007

Tags: outlook

Anyone knows how many attachments I can have it in single email sent via Outlook?

Answer (score 0):

it depends on your computer's config. But there are some thrid party utilities which allows you to add more attachments than what outlook can handle. http://kb.globalscape.com/KnowledgebaseArticle10629.aspx

it's advisable to use less attachments in outlook by zipping multiple attachments together. if you still need to send a lot of files (frequently), then use Dropbox, it's a free application that syncs a folder in your computer. they give 2 GB free. u can share a folder with your friend and exchange files in that way. Dropbox never crashes. you can signup for one here. http://db.tt/7EXHcXX

Answer (score 0):

There is **no such limit to the number of attachments** to be sent via outlook but the **size per attachment should not exceed 20MB**.

I hope that answers your query. Cheers :)